# Troubleshooting: Azure pipeline PowerShell task throwing 502 Bad Gateway response

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-applications, pipeline

My pipeline for deploy webapp on Azure fails on inline task Powershell.

Inside the script I make two web requests with:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType application/json
```

The first one works and I use part of response data to make a second POST but second call fails with code 502.

Here is the pipeline log:

```
An exception was caught: Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway).

Version             : 1.1
Content             : System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent
StatusCode          : BadGateway
ReasonPhrase        : Bad Gateway
Headers             : {[Date, System.String[]], [Cache-Control, System.String[]], [Pragma, System.String[]], 
                      [X-Content-Type-Options, System.String[]]…}
TrailingHeaders     : {}
RequestMessage      : Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://xxx.xxx.com/v3/xxx/xxx/RESPONSE_DATA_FROM_REQUEST_1/XXXXX', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, 
                      Headers:
                      {
                        Authorization: Bearer ***
                        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
                        User-Agent: (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763; en-US)
                        User-Agent: PowerShell/7.2.11
                        Content-Length: 416
                        Content-Type: application/json
                      }
IsSuccessStatusCode : False
```

---

If I run the same request with postman it works fine.
If I run script inside Powershell it works fine.
When I run inside pipeline it fails.

---

Here is my task on pipeline:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Perform smoke test
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      $Headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $(tokenVar)"}
      $body='{"user":{"id":"XXXXXXXXX"}}'
      $tentatives=3
      $counter=0
      $success=$false
      $progressPreference = "silentlyContinue"
      [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
      
      for ($i=1; $i -le $tentatives -And $success -eq $false; $i++)
      {
        try {
          $firstResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType application/json  `
          -Uri URL  `
          -Headers $Headers  `
          -Body $body  `
          -TimeoutSec 180
          $myId=$firstResponse.Id
      
          $secondBody='{"xx":"yy","zz":"ww"}'
          
          
          $secondResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType application/json  `
          -Uri "URL/$myId"  `
          -Headers $Headers  `
          -Body $secondBody  `
          -TimeoutSec 180
          $success=$true
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "An exception was caught: $($_.Exception.Message)"
            $_.Exception.Response
            $counter++
            Start-Sleep -s 5
        }
      }
      
      if ($success -eq $false)
      {
        Write-Host "Smoke test failed"
        exit 1
      }
      else
      {
        Write-Host "Smoke test successful"
      }
    pwsh: true
```

If I run the same request with postman it works fine.
If I run script inside Powershell it works fine.
When I run inside pipeline it fails.